# Android Handle ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, exception

I have read numerous threads on various websites on this topic including this one and have implemented many coding schemas to no avail. I am trying to handle an exception and no matter what I do the class crashes when the item in an array is not found.
my current code is this:

```
try{
                cur_index = java.util.Arrays.asList(itemName).indexOf(url) ;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.i("ERROR", "CATCH");
                alert.show();
            }
```

when url is not found in the itemName array a -1 is shown in the stack trace

07-22 13:42:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(25046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
07-22 13:42:32.339: E/AndroidRuntime(25046): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.laserpros.tech_to_go/com.laserpros.tech_to_go.MK_Gallery}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=80; index=-1

the catch log never shows. The alert dialog box just informs the user the item could not be found and then runs code to close the class.

any help would be apprcieated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having isn't with the code you're showing. When using the `indexOf` method, if the item isn't found in the list -1 is returned. The problem is that since that line of code is successful, it continues through your program, using the value of `cur_index` at a later point and throwing that exception.

Comment: but i tried using a if statement if(cur_index == -1) show alert and terminate function.

Comment: I see what your saying after debugging some more.. not sure I can get around this. Wish people wouldn't -1 a questions when  A person is just trying to learn.

Comment: thanks to your guidance I was able to get around this issue. I did so by reassigning cur_index and then was able to display the alertDialog and close the view if the item was not found. Thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I was able to help.